# org.dbunit.dataset.NoSuchColumnException

Tags: java, testing, dbunit, spring-test-dbunit

I'm getting the following error when I run my tests:

```
org.dbunit.dataset.NoSuchColumnException: myTable.MYFIELD -  (Non-uppercase input column: myfield) in ColumnNameToIndexes cache map. Note that the map's column names are NOT case sensitive.
    at org.dbunit.dataset.AbstractTableMetaData.getColumnIndex(AbstractTableMetaData.java:117)
```

I set a breakpoint in `org.dbunit.dataset.AbstractTableMetaData#getColumnIndex` and discovered the following. In IntelliJ Idea the method looks like this:

```
public int getColumnIndex(String columnName) throws DataSetException 
{
    logger.debug("getColumnIndex(columnName={}) - start", columnName);

    if(this._columnsToIndexes == null) 
    {
        // lazily create the map
        this._columnsToIndexes = createColumnIndexesMap(this.getColumns());
    }

    String columnNameUpperCase = columnName.toUpperCase();
    Integer colIndex = (Integer) this._columnsToIndexes.get(columnNameUpperCase);
    if(colIndex != null) 
    {
        return colIndex.intValue();
    }
    else 
    {
        throw new NoSuchColumnException(this.getTableName(), columnNameUpperCase,
                " (Non-uppercase input column: "+columnName+") in ColumnNameToIndexes cache map. " +
                "Note that the map's column names are NOT case sensitive.");
    }
}
```

The value of `this.getColumns()` does not contain any `Column` with `Column.columnName` matching the parameter `columnName`. Therefore `colIndex` becomes `null` and the exception is thrown.

It looks like DBUnit is looking for the column index in the wrong table meta data.

How can I fix this?

Note: I inherited this code from someone else (didn't write it).

Comment: Since you have already done a detailed analysis of the problem I guess the best place to ask this question is non the DBUnit support forum.

Comment: There are two possible reasons. Either the DBUnit is wrong. Or, you provided it wrong columnName in some annotation or wrongly named getter/setter pair.

Comment: You need to show a bit more code than that for someone to get a better idea of the situation. Also which table gets used in your case and did you check where it is coming from?

Comment: @TarunLalwani What exactly can I look for?

Comment: Some annotation or some setup code, also see which table is getting picked? That should give you a clue where the code is loading the table details from

Comment: Is this is a JPA project? How is the test database created? See also here to enable logging of all SQL being generated, including table creation and iserts https://stackoverflow.com/a/19299769/1356423

Comment: Could you share `createColumnIndexesMap()` method?

Comment: Three things: (a) what DOES `this.getColumns()` return? (b) what is the content of `this._columnsToIndexes`? (c) what is the table's DDL?

Comment: @DP_ How are you configuring your DbUnit env. Which DatabaseTester are you using? Can you share your DatabaseTester and it's details

Comment: Look AT https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2210429/dbunit-confusion-over-case-sensitivity-on-table-column-names

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm sensitive to the fact that you can't really share code.  That does make things a little difficult, but here's an answer I think is reasonable given the confines:

I was able to easily reproduce this exception using a [minimal Spring Boot/DbUnit project cloned from GitHub](https://github.com/21decemb/spring-boot-dbunit-example).  Perhaps my observations will amount to the hint you're looking for, or at least inspire a better answer.

**Steps**

- Clone [the project](https://github.com/21decemb/spring-boot-dbunit-example) and install dependencies.
- Run the `HsqldbexampleApplicationTests.contextLoads()` test.  It passes.
- Get into `StaticResource.java`, and change one of the `@Column` annotations.

For example, I changed:

```
@Column(name = "CONTENT")
private String content;
```

to:

```
@Column(name = "CONTENTZ")
private String content;
```

- Run the test again and observe the exception
- Alternatively, you can get into `sampleData.xml` and change the `CONTENT` attributes there (the attribute *name*), to produce the same exception.

**Observations**

- The test gets its data from `/META-INF/dbtest/sampleData.xml`.  Note the `CONTENT` attribute.
- The resource has an `@Column` annotation whose `name` must match an attribute found in the `sampleData.xml` elements.
- Since your trouble is also with running tests, it may be that your code and the `.xml`(?) that hydrates your test data store are simply out of sync with respect to a column name.

**Further implication of an XML file?**

My attempts to provoke this exception by changing queries and instance variable names were unsuccessful.  Everything I tried made the compiler complain, so I ruled it out.

For example, I also checked out [this repo](https://github.com/springtestdbunit/spring-test-dbunit), and tried to change a query and an instance variable, but was thwarted by the compiler at every step.  Changing a query:

[image: Changing query error]

Changing an instance variable name:

[image: Changing variable name error]

**Where to look**

- Anywhere in any java code where you have `@Column` with `MYFIELD` inside it.  Remember, annotations can span several lines in a file.
- Any xml files containing `MYFIELD`.
- Assuming the code under test works fine, and your problems are confined to running tests, the mechanism that injects data into your test is the prime suspect.  If this *isn't* an xml file, what is it?

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear from you post how do you get the `_columnsToIndexes` 
It looks like a piece of some reflection code that depends on your POJO.
In this case the problem migth be in `Lazy` initialization of the object. Lazy initialized objects are not just entity object but some kind of proxy and attemption of getting its properties through the reflection may cause this problem. 
Probably you should try add some kind of unproxy method into you `createColumnIndexesMap`. Here is example:

```
public static <T> T initializeAndUnproxy(T entity) {
    if (entity == null) {
      throw new InternalServerException("Entity passed for initialization is null");
    }

    T unproxy = entity;
    Hibernate.initialize(entity);
    if (isProxy(entity)) {
      unproxy = (T) ((HibernateProxy) entity).getHibernateLazyInitializer().getImplementation();
    }
    return unproxy;
  }
  public static <T> boolean isProxy(T entity) {
    return entity instanceof HibernateProxy;
  }
```

of course it depends on your ORM, here is example for Hibernate